# Adding a 2D numpy array 1D wise/element wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a ndarray with shape: 4x5

```py
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Is there any inbuild numpy function to add each row element-wise and get the result as:

```py
array([30, 34, 38, 42, 46])
```

Or any procedure to add those columns in constant amount of time?

Comment: `np.sum(array, axis=0)`? Sorry to disappoint, but "constant amount of time" will not be possible.

Comment: Try `arr.sum(0)`